# String validation based on multiple criteria

Tags: python, python-3.x, strings

I had me a code challenge and I was thinking: is there a way to make this more efficient and short? The challenge requires me to scan a string and ...

> - In the first line, print `True` if it has any alphanumeric characters. Otherwise, print `False`.
> - In the second line, print `True` if it has any alphabetical characters. Otherwise, print `False`.
> - In the third line, print `True` if it has any digits. Otherwise, print `False`.
> - In the fourth line, print `True` if it has any lowercase characters. Otherwise, print `False`.
> - In the fifth line, print `True` if  has any uppercase characters. Otherwise, print `False`.

Below is my approach :

```
def func_alnum(s):
    for i in s:
        if i.isalnum():
            return True
    return False

def func_isalpha(s):
    for i in s:
        if i.isalpha():
            return True
    return False

def func_isdigit(s):
    for i in s:
        if i.isdigit():
            return True
    return False  

def func_islower(s):
    for i in s:
        if i.islower():
            return True
    return False

def func_isupper(s):
    for i in s:
        if i.isupper():
            return True
    return False
if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = input()
    s=list(s)
    print(func_alnum(s))
    print(func_isalpha(s))
    print(func_isdigit(s))
    print(func_islower(s))
    print(func_isupper(s))
```

It feels like I made a mountain out of a molehill. But I would defer to your opinions on efficiency and shortness before I live with that opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your five functions only differ by the predicate used to test each character, so you could have a single one parametrized by said predicate:

```
def fulfill_condition(predicate, string):
    for character in string:
        if predicate(character):
            return True
    return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = input()
    print(fulfill_condition(str.isalnum, s))
    print(fulfill_condition(str.isalpha, s))
    print(fulfill_condition(str.isdigit, s))
    print(fulfill_condition(str.islower, s))
    print(fulfill_condition(str.isupper, s))
```

Note that you don't need to convert the string to a list for this to work, strings are already iterables.

Now we can simplify `fulfill_condition` even further by analysing that it applies the predicate to each character and returns whether any one of them is `True`. This can be written:

```
def fulfill_condition(predicate, string):
    return any(map(predicate, string))
```

Lastly, if you really want to have 5 different functions, you can use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
from functools import partial


func_alnum = partial(fulfill_condition, str.isalnum)
func_isalpha = partial(fulfill_condition, str.isalpha)
func_isdigit = partial(fulfill_condition, str.isdigit)
func_islower = partial(fulfill_condition, str.islower)
func_isupper = partial(fulfill_condition, str.isupper)
```

Comment: Thanks. It helps to know other efficient approach to solve a problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is done using list comprehensions and `any()` in python.

We can use the following to make it more faster.

```
print(any([i.isalnum() for i in string]))
```

Since we are only looking for any 1 element in the string being an uppercase,lowercase, etc Any() finds a good use case here.

Comment: `any` can also take an iterator instead of a list. It stops the iteration as soon as it encounters a `True` element. So if you remove the square brackets, it's even faster.